# log-scale line is filled in, looks like a semi-circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I attempt to create a semi-log plot with background data and fit lines, the fit lines end up looking completely wonky.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k=0

for i in np.arange(0,len(emceeredshifts),7):
    zbin=emceeredshifts[i+1]
    lowradius = radius[(redshift <= (zbin + halfwidth)) & (redshift >= (zbin - halfwidth)) & (radius > 1) & (radius<20) &(mass>10.5)].flatten()
    lowmass = mass[(redshift <= (zbin + halfwidth)) & (redshift >= (zbin - halfwidth)) & (radius > 1) & (radius<20)&(mass>10.5)].flatten()
    if len(lowradius)>0:
        lowfit = np.polyfit(lowmass, lowradius, 1)
        lowlin,lowinter=np.poly1d(lowfit)
        lowbestfit = lowinter + lowlin * (lowmass )
        plt.plot( lowmass, lowbestfit, color=rainbowcolors[k], label=str(zbin))
    plt.scatter( lowmass, lowradius, color=rainbowcolors[k], marker='.', alpha=.2, edgecolor='none')
    k+=1

plt.legend(loc='lower right')

plt.title("Galaxy radius vs mass\nlinear mcmc mass predictions")
plt.xlabel("Log $M_\odot$")
plt.ylabel("Physical radius (kpc)")
plt.ylim(2,15)
plt.xlim(10.6,11.8)

plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Here is the buggy semi-log result. 
[image: Buggy log-scale matplotlib line plot]

And here is what I get when I remove the log scale. When the y axis is linear, lines look like lines and data looks like data.
[image: Linear scale plot]

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the content of the arrays used to plot those lines? I suspect they are not sorted, and so mpl is drawing the line back and forth between the points. In linear-space, this just amounts to drawing along the same line, so you don't see it, but in log-space, it is noticeable because of the curved line.

I think this minimal example demonstrates the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(1000)
y = x.copy()

fig,(ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3,figsize=(7,7))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)

ax1.plot(x,y)
ax1.set_title('linear')

ax2.plot(x,y)
ax2.set_yscale('log')
ax2.set_title('log, unsorted')

ind=np.argsort(x)
ax3.plot(x[ind],y[ind])
ax3.set_yscale('log')
ax3.set_title('log, sorted')

plt.show()
```

[image]